# How can I insert values into a Treeview using a function and a loop? (not insert)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tkinter, treeview

I would like to insert the values `4, 1, 7, 5, 9, 3` into the Badge column of the Treeviews, using `column = function()` (not `treeview.insert`) and loop

As you can see, i unpacked each list and then repacked it with `Rank = record[0], Name = record[1], and Badge = example()`. And also i use `values = datagrid`. I know there are better ways, but I need to **maintain** this code.

Currently in the Badge column of the Treeview I see `4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4`. Instead I would like to print `4, 1, 7, 5, 9, 3`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws['bg']='#fb0'

data  = [
    [1,"Jack"],
    [2,"Tom"],
    [3,"Daniel"],
    [4,"Leonard"],
    [5,"Frank"],
    [6,"Robert"],
    ]

tv = ttk.Treeview(ws)
tv['columns']=('Rank', 'Name', 'Badge')
tv.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
tv.column('Rank', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.column('Name', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.column('Badge', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Rank', text='Id', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Name', text='rank', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Badge', text='Badge', anchor=CENTER)
tv.pack()


def func1():

    def example():
        x  = [
            ["4"],
            ["1"],
            ["7"],
            ["5"],
            ["9"],
            ["3"],
            ]

        for a in x:
            return a

    for index, record in enumerate(data):
        Rank = record[0]
        Name = record[1]
        Badge = example()
        
        datagrid = [Rank, Name, Badge]
        tv.insert(parent='', index='end', values=(datagrid))

   

button = Button(ws, text="Button", command = func1)
button.place(x=1, y=1)

ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: using `return` in function it will allways run all code from the beginning and it will always use first element from list. You have to use `yield` instead of `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `return` in function it will allways run all code in function from the beginning and it will always use first element from list.

You have to use `yield` instead of `return`. It will create generator and it will need also `next()` to get next value from generator.

```
def example():
    x  = [
        ["4"],
        ["1"],
        ["7"],
        ["5"],
        ["9"],
        ["3"],
        ]

    for a in x:
        yield a

gen = example()   

for index, record in enumerate(data):
    Rank = record[0]
    Name = record[1]
    Badge = next(gen)

    # ... rest ...
```

You may also use generator directly in `for` without `next()`
(it needs `( )` after `for` to correctly assign values from `zip()`)

```
gen =  example()   

for (index, record), Badge in zip(enumerate(data), gen):
    Rank = record[0]
    Name = record[1]

    # ... rest ...
```

But frankly, I would use directly `x` without creating `example()`

```
x  = [["4"],["1"],["7"],["5"],["9"],["3"],]

for (index, record), Badge in zip(enumerate(data), x):
    Rank = record[0]
    Name = record[1]

    # ... rest ...
```